# OpenOffice Calc - find last cell in a row with data

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet which contains a list of songs and the dates that they are used.
I would like to be able to have a cell at the beginning of the list of dates, which simply displays the last date the particular song is used.

I have been unable to find a formula function which will do this, which does not mean that it doesn't exist.

So, to reduce the question : I need a formula which will find the last, non blank cell in a given row or range of cells.

In addition, there can exist cells which are blank between filled in rows.

Can an openoffice expert help me here, please ?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I had this need too in OpenOffice Calc (version 4.1.3).

I could solve it with Array formulas, ie, pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to leave the cell:

Last number in a row:

```
=MAX(ISNUMBER(A1:A1048576)*ROW(A1:A1048576))
```

Last text in a row:

```
=MAX(ISTEXT(A1:A1048576)*ROW(A1:A1048576))
```

Last non-empty cell in a row:

```
=MAX(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A1048576))*ROW(A1:A1048576))
```

The three above functions work even if you have empty cells in between, before the last one.

As for Date, I could not come with a specific answer, but at LibreOffice help there is an useful thread discussing [criterias to check if cell value is a date.](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/238080/criteria-to-check-if-cell-value-is-a-date/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the latest date why not use

```
=MAX(A1:A1048576)
```

Unfortunately, OpenOffice does not support (A:A) to address the whole column...

Alternatively you could record a macro where you go to cell A1048576 first and then use Ctrl+Up to jump to the last used cell.